# Can't upload data image in OpenStack using curl

Tags: curl, openstack, openstack-glance

After i create an image, i'd want to upload a cirros.img image that i download from

```
http://download.cirros-cloud.net/0.3.5/
```

I try with the PUT api request like openstack documentation says but it returns me always an error and the image has 0 MB size.

The command i use is:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "X-Auth-Token: $Token" -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" -d "@/home/nic/cirros.img" 192.168.1.107:9292/v2/images/$ID_IMAGE/file
```

Comment: What error message is returned?

Comment: Warning: Couldn't read data from file "cirros.img", this makes an empty POST.
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
X-Openstack-Request-Id: req-41d9b859-bae6-4426-a2e3-d458789f5ae4
Date: Sun, 03 Dec 2017 16:35:58 GMT